# Using Manipulate with inequality constraint

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

I'm trying to manipulate the plot of the following function:

```
f[a_, λ_, n_, t_, c_] := -((n*(-1 + λ)*(a^2 + a^n)*c*(-4*λ*a + (-1 + λ)^2*a^2*c + 
        (-1 + λ)^2*a^n*c))/(16*t*(1 + λ)*a^2))

Manipulate[
 Plot[ f[a, λ, n, t, c], 
 {c, 0, 1}], {λ, 0, 1}, 
 {a, 0.01, 1}, 
 {t, 0.01, 1000}, 
 {n, 5, 1000}
]
```

where the domain for each parameter has been introduced in `Manipulate`: $\lambda\in[0,1]$, $a\in(0,1]$, $t>0$, and $n\geq 5$. However, my parametric space is constrained by

$t\geq \dfrac{a\ n^2}{2}$

and

$\lambda\ a \leq \dfrac{4}{5}$

How can I introduce those constraints into `Manipulate`? That is

1. I want the manipulators to move freely while the constraint is slack;
2. Once the constraint binds, I want the manipulators to move in sync, ensuring that the constraint is not violated

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161014/parameter-space-constraint-in-manipulate) presents a case in which the manipulators move in sync to ensure that an **equality** constraint holds. If my constraints were equality constraints, then the solution would be:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[a_, λ_, n_, t_, c_] := -((n*(-1 + λ)*(a^2 + a^n)*
      c*(-4*λ*a + (-1 + λ)^2*a^2*c + 
             (-1 + λ)^2*a^n*c))/(16*t*(1 + λ)*a^2))
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Plot[f[a, λ, n, t, c], {c, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
     ImageSize -> 400]}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}], 
 Grid[{{"a ", Manipulator[Dynamic[a, {a = #; t = a*n^2/2;
        λ = 4/(5*a)} &], {0.01, 1}], 
    Dynamic[NumberForm[a, {3, 3}]]},

   {"t ", Manipulator[Dynamic[t, {t = #;
        a = 2*t/n^2;
        λ = 4/(5*a)} &], {0.01, 1000}], 
    Dynamic[NumberForm[t, {3, 3}]]},

   {"λ ", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[λ, {λ = #; a = 4/(5*λ); 
        t = a*n^2/2} &], {0, 1}], 
    Dynamic[NumberForm[λ, {3, 3}]]},

   {"n ", Manipulator[Dynamic[n, {n = #;
            t = a*n^2/2} &], {5, 1000}], 
    Dynamic[NumberForm[n, {3, 3}]]}

   }], {{a, 2*Sqrt[5.0]/5}, None}, {{t, 20*Sqrt[5.0]}, 
  None}, {{λ, 2*Sqrt[5.0]/5}, None}, {{n, 10}, None}, 
 Alignment -> Center, SynchronousUpdating -> True, 
 SynchronousInitialization -> True, FrameMargins -> 1, 
 ImageMargins -> 1, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

With **inequality** constraints, how can I make `Manipulate` do what is laid out in points 1. and 2. above?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What behavior would you expect for e.g. $t$ as the value of $c$ changes across the plot?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161014/parameter-space-constraint-in-manipulate describes a similar problem but with an equality constraint. There, the introduction of a second argument ensured that the parameters moved in sync. Here, suppose I'm changing parameter $t$. I want it to move freely while the constraint is slack; once the constraint binds, I want it to behave similar to the case linked

Comment: OK so could you include that link in the question and modify your code according to the suggestions made there, then point out any remaining problems with it?

Comment: @MarcoB ok, done

Comment: Actually, `Table` and other similar routines can accept the dynamically updated limits for certain inner ranges if these limits are calculated in outer loop. So, you should try with such order `{t,...0.5an^2},{Lambda,...4/(5a)},{n,...},{a,...}`